# ¿Como comprobar variables request.data? DRF

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Estoy modificando un servicio de una API en Django Rest Framework y tengo un error a comprobar si existe un campo en el JSON que envía el cliente.

Tengo un ViewSet de Comentarios que puede estar asociado a un producto o un look, entonces, en el `create()` del servicio quiero comprobar si existe el campo `producto` cree un comentario asociado a producto y sino lo cree asociado a un look.

Mi código ahora mismo es este:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
    if request.data['producto']:
        comentario = Comentario.objects.create(perfil= perfil,comentario=request.data['comentario'],ip=obtener_ip(request),
            producto=Producto.objects.get(id=request.data['producto']))
    elif request.data['look']:
        comentario = Comentario.objects.create(perfil= perfil,comentario=request.data['comentario'],ip=obtener_ip(request),
            look=Look.objects.get(id=request.data['look']))
    serializer = ComentarioSerializer(instance=comentario)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

El JSON que necesito enviar es este:

> Para productos:`{ producto: 1, comentario: "prueba comentario" }`
>
> Para look: `{ look: 3, comentario: "prueba comentario"}`

Comment: En principio el test debe ser `if 'producto' in request.data:`  y  `elif 'look' in request.data:`.

Comment: Ahora si funciona, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
if "key" in request.data:
    #Proceso si existe la clave
else:
    #Proceso si no existe la clave
```

O, si necesitas que si no viene la clave otorgar un valor por default puedes optar por

```
variable = request.data.get("key", default)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).